# Elastic Search - Wagtail - Geo distance

Tags: elasticsearch, wagtail

I would like to implement a search where the user enter a city and the wagtail API return models that are in the area of this city.

- User type a city
- With geocoding (for exemple Google API), I retrieve the lat . Long.
- Use Wagtail API + ElasticSearch to find models that matches the lat/long + a radius

Is it possible to set up Elastic Search feature (geo distance) with Wagtail API in order to retrieve models that matches a specific radius of latitude / longitude ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like the BakeryDemo Locations App(very simple):

define your properties like:

```
address = models.TextField()
lat_long = models.CharField(
    max_length=36,
    help_text="Comma separated lat/long. (Ex. 64.144367, -21.939182) \
               Right click Google Maps and select 'What\'s Here'",
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            regex=r'^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$',
            message='Lat Long must be a comma-separated numeric lat and long',
            code='invalid_lat_long'
        ),
    ]
)
```

Define exposed fields into API like:

```
api_fields = [
    APIField('address'),
    APIField('lat_long'),
    # + whatever else you need . . !
]
```

Create needed context_variables (if you need them in a template, otherwise expose them to API as well):

```
# Makes additional context available to the template so that we can access
# the latitude, longitude and map API key to render the map
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super(LocationPage, self).get_context(request)
    context['lat'] = self.lat_long.split(",")[0]
    context['long'] = self.lat_long.split(",")[1]
    context['google_map_api_key'] = settings.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY
    return context
```

include the follwing scrpt into your template (API caller function):

```
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: {{lat}},
            lng: {{long}}
        },
        zoom: 15,
        scrollwheel: false
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: {{lat}},
            lng: {{long}}
        },
        map: map,
        title: '{{page.title}}'
    });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ google_map_api_key }}&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

**For Searching..!**
Wagtail provides an API to perform search queries on your models. You can also perform search queries on Django QuerySets.

See [Searching](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/search/searching.html#wagtailsearch-searching).